# Retrieve non-NULL column from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to write a query in sql server from below table:

```
**Column-1** **Column-2** **Column-**3
  x              Null         Null
 Null             y           Null
 Null            Null          z
```

and my output will be:

```
**Columnname**
    x
    y
    z
```

Please send me the result as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Columnname = COALESCE([Column-1],[Column-2],[Column-3]) FROM dbo.tablename;
```